# Shared Database in application and webserver

Tags: java, php, database, sqlite, jetty

I wrote an application which uses a SQLite database, now I want to extend the apllication with a webinterface.

Since I want everything to be in one application with no need to set anything up or install something else I plan to embed Jetty in the application and then install some CGI servlet to use PHP.

The application and the website should be able to modify the database.

This is most likely not to be accomplished with SQLite.

What ideas do you have to accomplish this? Important is that everything can be integrated into one application.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you access the database only via a [`javax.sql.DataSource`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sql/DataSource.html) definition from JNDI, and you are golden, as both sides, both the Application and the WebApp will have the same access patterns, techniques, rules, etc ...

Comment: I am pretty sure you can't access javax.sql.Datasource from php

Comment: You can access a surprising array of java features from php.  But I agree, don't try.  You will have an interesting setup there, but I would recommend using the FastCGI features instead of standard CGI with PHP from Jetty.  Much easier setup and far more reliable.

Comment: Still the initial problem remains, normally I would use a MySQL database, but I want to deplaoy everything in one simple package.